# Applying equal margin to a Div inside a fixed Div

Tags: css, html, margin, fixed

i'm trying to create a fixed panel in the bottom of page that has 5px of margin from bottom,left and right. I though best way is to put a div inside a fixed div and then play with margins and paddings... but i can't make it happen. either left side or right side denies the margin! you can see the live example here :

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uEBqD
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us your html and css and may be a jsfiddle.

Comment: @freebird here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Ju9e4/

Comment: Do you want to apply margin to inner div

Comment: @freebird yes exactly. but it only applies to "left and bottom" or "right and bottom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made too many CSS rules, just give some margin/padding to the inner DIV, and leave the other properties.

Your updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cJled

Comment: nope! it's not what i was trying to accomplish. in your example there is no left and right margin.

Comment: the real deal i was looking for http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vkDEF thanks for your help Hidde